# How to count rows ordered by the first field in bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

Here is a snippet from the INPUT:

```
...
####################
Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A
SERVER345Z3.DOMAIN.com0
SERVER346Z3.DOMAIN.com0
SERVER347Z3.DOMAIN.com0
SERVER348Z3.DOMAIN.com0
ssh-dss ...pubkeyhere...
####################
Ize Jova;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345;A
SERVER342Z3.DOMAIN.com0
SERVER343Z3.DOMAIN.com0
SERVER345Z3.DOMAIN.com0
ssh-rsa ...pubkeyhere...
...
```

And here is a snippet from the OUTPUT that I need:

```
Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A
4
Ize Jova;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345;A
3
```

So I need an OUTPUT from the INPUT, so that I could see that how many rows starting with "SERVER" goes to given user (ex.: "Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A"). How can I do this in bash?

Comment: Do you require this to be standalone Bash, or are other tools acceptable (grep, awk, perl...)?

Comment: i would assume (and have done so :) that, unless explicitly stated otherwise, a bash scripting question allows all the standard tools like grep, awk, sed, perl and all the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case "$line" in
    ssh*|'##'*)
      ;;
    SERVER*)
      ((++i))
      ;;
    *)
      if ((i>0)); then echo $i;i=0; fi
      echo "$line"
      ;;
  esac
done
if ((i>0)); then echo $i;i=0; fi
} <inputfile >outputfile
```

The same in perl one-liner

```
perl -nle '
  BEGIN{$i=0}
  next if/^(ssh|##)/;
  if(/^SERVER/){++$i;next}
  print$i if$i>0;
  $i=0;
  print;
  END{print$i if$i>0}' inputfile >outputfile
```

and golfed

```
perl -nle's/^(ssh|##|(SERVER))/$2&&$i++/e&&next;$i&&print$i;$i=!print}{$i&&print$i' inputfile >outputfile
```

Comment: wow. perl is amazing :D

Answer (score 5):

This version counts all rows that don't match the regexp in the `grep` line.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

# set the Input Record Separator (man perlvar for details)
$/ = '####################';

while(<>) {
    # split the rows into an array
    my @rows = split "\n";

    # get rid of the elements we're not interested in
    @rows = grep {!/^#######|^ssh-|^$/} @rows;

    # first row of array is the title, and "scalar @rows"
    # is the number of entries, so subtract 1.
    if (scalar(@rows) gt 1) {
      print "$rows[0]\n", scalar @rows -1, "\n"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A
4
Ize Jova;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345;A
3
```

If you *only* want to count lines beginning with 'SERVER', then:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

# set the Input Record Separator (man perlvar for details)
$/ = '####################';

while(<>) {
    # split the rows into an array
    my @rows = split "\n";

    # $rows[0] will be same as $/ or '', so get title from $rows[1]
    my $title = $rows[1];

    my $count = grep { /^SERVER/} @rows;

    if ($count gt 0) {
      print "$title\n$count\n"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -n ':a /^SERVER/{g;p;ba}; h' file | uniq -c | 
  sed -r 's/^ +([0-9]) (.*)/\2\n\1/'
```

Output:

```
Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A
4
Ize Jova;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345;A
3
```

---

If a prefixed count is ok:

```
sed -n ':a /^SERVER/{g;p;ba}; h' file |uniq -c
```

Output:

```
  4 Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A
  3 Ize Jova;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345;A
```

Answer (score 4):

An `awk` alternative:

```awk
/^#{15,}/ {           # if line starts with 15 or more number signs
  if(k) {             # if any key found
    print k RS n      # print it and occurrences of SERVER
    n=0
  }
  getline             # key is on the next line
  k = $0
  next                # move to next record
} 

/SERVER/ { n++ }      # count occurrences of SERVER
END { print k RS n }  # print last record
```

All on one line:

```
awk '/^#{15,}/ { if(n>0) { print k RS n; n=0 }; getline; k = $0; next } /SERVER/ { n++ } END { print k RS n }'
```

Answer (score 2):

So If the output is already sorted in each "bucket" you could directly apply uniq with checking only the first N characters:

```
cat x | uniq -c -w6
```

Here is N==6 as SERVER consists of 6 characters from the beginning of the line. You will end up with this output (which is a bit different from your required output):

```
  1 ####################
  1 Bala Bela;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345678;A
  4 SERVER345Z3.DOMAIN.com0
  1 ssh-dss ...pubkeyhere...
  1 ####################
  1 Ize Jova;XXXXXX12345;XXXXXX12345;A
  3 SERVER342Z3.DOMAIN.com0
  1 ssh-rsa ...pubkeyhere...
```